# Where I can find complete list of operations supported by input fields?

Tags: interface

Where I can find complete list of (arithmetic and not) operations supported by input fields in advanced mode?

The [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/precision/numeric_input.html#advanced-mode) says:

> - Units (cm, “, deg, etc.).
> - Basic operations from python/BKE_unit (+,    *, **, etc.), and math constants and functions (pi, sin, etc.).

But i whant to see complete list of all supported operators, functions, constants...

Answer (score 3):

First Blender evaluates all units used. Basically:

1. The default unit is figured: out of all units available in the current unit system (so an inch won't be a default unit if a metric system is used, even if it appears in the string), trying in this order:

   a) first unit found in the string entered,

   b) first unit found in the previous value that is now being replaced,

   c) the default unit for the field type.
2. Then all units are converted to the default unit, for technicalities how it's done, you can study the [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/blenkernel/intern/unit.c#L1092).
3. A backup of the `__Main__` Python module is created, then the original is used so that the code like below works:

```py
>> foo = 10
>> print(__import__("__main__").foo)
```

4. Once all units are converted to the default unit, all calculations are done disregarding that unit. This means inputting `1 km * 1 km` will result with `1 km` and not `1 km2`. Units from other categories than the one associated with a field can't be used, e.g. you can't input `1 km3 / 1 km2` into a location field, because the cubic kilometer won't be divided by a square kilometer to produce a valid km unit for this field.
5. The main module is restored from the backup.

There isn't really any limit to what can be done, it's full unlimited Python. If you disable the unit system (set it to *None*), then you can paste the below code into a field like *Location X*:

```py
[exec("import numpy as np\na=float(np.nextafter(np.float32(10e6), np.float32('inf')))"), a][1]
```

And you will get `10000001` as a result. It won't work with a unit system turned on, because then the quotes will be interpreted as feet / inches. In rotation fields as arcminutes / arcseconds. But e.g. in *vertex mass*, since those symbols aren't used for weight, it will work.

### Units

Here's the list of all units. I removed information not relevant to the question and concentrated on the logic of inputting values, disregarding Blender's logic of displaying them:

**Metric length:**

- `km` = 1000, `kilometer`,  `kilometers`
- `hm` = 100, `hectometer`, `hectometers`
- `dam`= 10, `dekameter`,  `dekameters`
- **`m` = 1, `meter`,      `meters` - default**
- `dm`= 0.1, `decimeter`,  `decimeters`
- `cm` = 0.01, `centimeter`, `centimeters`
- `mm` = 0.001, `millimeter`, `millimeters`
- `µm` = 0.000001, `um`, `micrometer`, `micrometers`

**Imperial length:**

- `mi` = 1609.344, `mile`,    `miles`
- `fur`= 201.168, `furlong`, `furlongs`
- `ch` = 20.1168, `chain`,   `chains`
- `yd` = 0.9144, `yard`,    `yards`
- **`'` = 0.3048, `ft`, `foot`,    `feet` - default**
- `"` = 0.0254, `in`, `inch`,    `inches`
- `thou`= 0.0000254, `mil`

**Metric Area**

- `km²` = 1000², `km2`, `square kilometer`,  `square kilometers`
- `hm²` = 100², `hm2`, `square hectometer`, `square hectometers`
- `dam²`= 10², `dam2`, `square dekameter`,  `square dekameters`
- **`m²` = 1, `m2`, `square meter`,  `square meters` - default**
- `dm²` = 0.1², `dm2`, `square decimeter`,  `square decimetees`
- `cm²` = 0.01²  `cm2`, `square centimeter`, `square centimeters`
- `mm²` = 0.001², `mm2`, `square millimeter`, `square millimeters`
- `µm²` = 0.000001², `um2`, `square micrometer`, `square micrometers`

**Imperial Area**

- `sq mi` = 1609.344², `sq m`, `square mile`,    `square miles`
- `sq fur`= 201.168², `square furlong`, `square furlongs`
- `sq ch` = 20.1168², `square chain`,   `square chains`
- `sq yd` = 0.9144², `square yard`,    `square yards`
- **`sq ft` = 0.3048², `square foot`,    `square feet` - default**
- `sq in` = 0.0254², `square inch`,    `square inches`
- `sq mil` = 0.0000254², `square thou`

**Metric Volume**

- `km³` = 1000³, `km3`, `cubic kilometer`,  `cubic kilometers`
- `hm³` = 100³, `hm3`, `cubic hectometer`, `cubic hectometers`
- `dam³`= 10³, `dam3`, `cubic dekameter`,  `cubic dekameters`
- **`m³` = 1, `m3`, `cubic meter`,  `cubic meters`- default**
- `dm³` = 0.1³, `dm3`, `cubic decimeter`,  `cubic decimetees`
- `cm³` = 0.01³  `cm3`, `cubic centimeter`, `cubic centimeters`
- `mm³` = 0.001³, `mm3`, `cubic millimeter`, `cubic millimeters`
- `µm³` = 0.000001³, `um3`, `cubic micrometer`, `cubic micrometers`

**Imperial Volume**

- `cu mi` = 1609.344³, `cu m`, `cubic mile`,    `cubic miles`
- `cu fur`= 201.168³, `cubic furlong`, `cubic furlongs`
- `cu ch` = 20.1168³, `cubic chain`,   `cubic chains`
- `cu yd` = 0.9144³, `cubic yard`,    `cubic yards`
- **`cu ft` = 0.3048³, `cubic foot`,    `cubic feet` - default**
- `cu in` = 0.0254³, `cubic inch`,    `cubic inches`
- `cu mil` = 0.0000254³, `cubic thou`

**Metric Weight**

- `ton` = 1000, `t`, `ton`,       `tonnes`
- `ql` = 100, `q`, `quintal`,   `quintals`
- **`kg` = 1, `kilogram`,  `kilograms` - default**
- `hg` = 0.1, `hectogram`, `hectograms`
- `dag` = 0.01, `dekagram`,  `dekagrams`
- `g` = 0.001, `gram`,      `grams`
- `mg` = 0.000001, `milligram`, `milligrams`

**Imperial Weight**

- `ton` = 907.18474, `t`, `ton`,           `tonnes`
- `cwt` = 45.359237, `centum weight`, `centum weights`
- `st` = 6.35029318, `stone`,         `stones`
- **`lb` = 0.45359237, `pound`,         `pounds` - default**
- `oz` = 0.028349523125, `ounce`,         `ounces`

**Metric Velocity**

- **`m/s` = 1, `meter per second`,   `meters per second` - default**
- `km/h` = 1000/3600, `kilometer per hour`, `kilometers per hour`

**Imperial Velocity**

- **`ft/s` = 0.3048, `fps`, `foot per second`, `feet per second` - default**
- `mph` = 1609.344/3600, `mile per hour`,   `miles per hour`

**Metric Acceleration**

- **`m/s²` = 1, `m/s2`, `meter per second squared`, `meters per second squared` - default**

**Imperial Acceleration**

- **`ft/s²` = 0.3048, `ft/s2`, `foot per second squared`, `feet per second squared` - default**

**Natural Time** (all unit systems including *"None"*)

- `d` = 90000, `day`,         `days` - **WARNING!** 90k/3.6k = 25 - do Blender devs live on Mars?
- `hr` = 3600, `h`, `hour`,        `hours`
- `min` = 60, `m`, `minute`,      `minutes`
- **`sec` = 1, `s`, `second`,      `seconds` - default**
- `ms` = 0.001, `millisecond`, `milliseconds`
- `µs`, `us` =  `microsecond`, `microseconds`

**Natural Rotation** (all unit systems including *"None"*)

- `°` = π/180, `d`, `degree`,    `degrees` - default unit displayed
- `'` = °/60, `arcminute`, `arcminutes`
- `"` = °/3600, `arcsecond`, `arcseconds`
- `r` = 1, `radian`,    `radians` - default unit internally

**Camera Length** (Metric but also used by Imperial setting)

- **`m` = 1, `meter`,      `meters` - default**
- `dm`= 0.1, `decimeter`,  `decimeters`
- `cm` = 0.01, `centimeter`, `centimeters`
- `mm` = 0.001, `millimeter`, `millimeters`
- `µm` = 0.000001, `um`, `micrometer`, `micrometers`

**Light Power** (Metric but also used by Imperial setting)

- `GW` = 1000'000'000, `gigawatt`,  `gigawatts`
- `MW` = 1000'000, `megawatt`,  `megawatts` - **CASE SENSITIVE**
- `kW` = 1000, `kilowatt`,  `kilowatts`
- **`W` = 1, `watt`,      `watts` - default**
- `mW` = 0.001, `milliwatt`, `milliwatts` - **CASE SENSITIVE**
- `µW` = 0.000'001, `uW`,`microwatt`, `microwatts`
- `nW` = 0.000'000'001, `nanowatt`,  `nanowatts`

**Metric Temperature**

- **`K` = 1, `kelvin`,  `kelvin` - default**
- `°C` = 1, `C`, `celsius` - bias of `273.15` (for conversion to/from Kelvin)

**Imperial Temperature**

- **`K` = 1, `kelvin`,  `kelvin` - default**
- `°F` = 0.555555555555, `F`, `fahrenheit`, - bias of `459.67` (for conversion to/from Kelvin)

### Python modules available

If you don't want to use `exec` trick to import modules, you can use directly builtin and math functions (`math` module is [already imported](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/master/source/blender/python/generic/py_capi_utils.c#L1427)):

**Builtin functions**:
`__build_class__`, `__import__`, `abs`, `all`, `any`, `ascii`, `bin`, `breakpoint`, `callable`, `chr`, `compile`, `delattr`, `dir`, `divmod`, `eval`, `exec`, `format`, `getattr`, `globals`, `hasattr`, `hash`, `hex`, `id`, `input`, `isinstance`, `issubclass`, `iter`, `aiter`, `len`, `locals`, `max`, `min`, `next`, `anext`, `oct`, `ord`, `pow`, `print`, `repr`, `round`, `setattr`, `sorted`, `sum`, `vars`, `open`

(and some non-function objects that probably aren't very useful, but you can easily print them - see the examples section)

**Math constants**:
`pi`, `e`, `tau`, `inf`, `nan`

**Math functions**:
`acos`, `acosh`, `asin`, `asinh`, `atan`, `atan2`, `atanh`, `ceil`, `copysign`, `cos`, `cosh`, `degrees`, `dist`, `erf`, `erfc`, `exp`, `expm1`, `fabs`, `factorial`, `floor`, `fmod`, `frexp`, `fsum`, `gamma`, `gcd`, `hypot`, `isclose`, `isfinite`, `isinf`, `isnan`, `isqrt`, `lcm`, `ldexp`, `lgamma`, `log`, `log1p`, `log10`, `log2`, `modf`, `pow`, `radians`, `remainder`, `sin`, `sinh`, `sqrt`, `tan`, `tanh`, `trunc`, `prod`, `perm`, `comb`, `nextafter`, `ulp`

### Examples

Paste this code to an input field - some will not work with a unit system enabled because of the usage of a unit - usually `"` or `'`:

1. **Print all non-function builtin objects available:**

```py
print(*[k for k, v in __builtins__.items() if type(v) is not type(id)], sep="\n")
```

2. **A hack to set field value to the inf:**

```py
nextafter(inf, 0)
```

click on the field afterwards to get the largest possible float instead. Preceed `inf` with a minus to get the smallest value.

3. **Make sure your system console is opened**, and enter this to hang Blender and start debugging the Python context:

```py
breakpoint()
```

Type `exit` in console to quit debugging.

4. **Evaluate a python expression written in a `E:/a` file:**

```py
eval([f:=open("E:/a"),f.read(),f.close()][1])
```

Example contents of the file:

```py
[exec("import random\na=random.random()"), a][1]
```

So it just randomizes a number in range [0;1]

5. **Same as above, but it works in *Length/Rotation* fields with a unit system enabled, also without the pedantic `close()`:**

```py
eval(open(str().join(map(chr,[69,58,47,97]))).read())
```

Comment: Great research, but I've asked a different thing. For example, I often use `pi` in geometry nodes to convert degrees to radians, and `sin` for example to get in-and-out motion with fading. That other functions like this can be used?

Comment: @Crantisz all math functions and functions from other modules listed at the end of the answer. And, as I wrote at the beginning, you can actually import additional modules using `exec`.

Comment: hm... I miss that, can you point it out?

Comment: Cannot find any function like sin or constraint like pi in your answer

Comment: Oh, I must have missed this post! +1 ...a great overview! Do you maintain this also in case of changes?

Comment: @quellenform not really, though I always read changelogs from cover to cover, so if changelogs ever mention input changes, likely I'll update this answer as well. A different things is Python updates, but I guess eventually I can refresh the builtins list.

Answer (score 2):

The latest information (Blender 3.1) on this topic can be found here:
[Numeric Input](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/numeric_input.html#advanced-mode)

Advanced Mode:

- [Units](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/scene_layout/scene/properties.html#units)
- [Basic operations from Python](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_operators.asp)
- [Math constants and functions](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html)